# Saving the output of Xpath in a Hive Table

Tags: xpath, hadoop, hive

I am using xpath to parse data that already exists in a Hive table.

I'm using the following commands:

create view xmlout104(line) as  select * from testdata104 limit 100;
select xpath(line,'MC/SC/S/@art') from xmlout104 limit 1;

I just wonder, How can I save the output in a new Hive Table.

That's the output:

["The Band","The Band","The Cascades","Creedence Clearwater Revival","Johnny Cash","Bob Seger","The Eagles","Johnny Horton","Marty Robbins","Bob Seger","Conway Twitty","Kenny Rogers & The First Edition","Neil Young","Neil Young","The Springfields","The Statler Brothers","The Statler Brothers","The Statler Brothers","Steve Miller Band","Steve Miller Band","Gale Garnett","Various Artists","Willie Nelson","The Eagles","The Eagles","The Highwaymen","Marty Robbins","Marty Robbins","The Highwaymen","Roy Clark","Roy Clark","Simon & Garfunkel","The Oak Ridge Boys","Vern Gosdin","Vern Gosdin","John Denver","John Denver","Vince Gill","Vince Gill","Vince Gill","Waylon Jennings","Waylon Jennings"]

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the table's schema you want to have, the most basic way to insert a query result into a table, e.g:

```
create table results(res string);
insert overwrite table results [select statement]
```

For more examples, have a look at the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/gettingstarted.html#GettingStarted-SELECTSandFILTERS):

Comment: When I use insert overwrite table results with select xpath , I get an exception;

Comment: Could you post the insert statement as well as the stack trace?